# Use string format in razor view to concat javascript variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, string.format

How can I write

```
var releaseName = $('#SelectedReleaseId option:selected').text()
var templateName = $('#SelectedTemplateId option:selected').text()
```

this:

```
$("#TestplanName").text(releaseName + '-' + templateName + '-' + '@Model.UserId' + '-' + '@Model.CreatedAt');
```

into:

```
$("#TestplanName").text( '@string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",releaseName,templateName,@Model.UserId,@Model.CreatedAt)');
```

The releaseName and templateName are unknown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You're trying to mix **client-side** variables – which only exist in Javascript on the client – with server-side code.

Instead, you can use a Javascript equivalent of `string.Format`.

Comment: thanks I used the  $.validator.format(xxx) as I use jquery anyway.